# Django filter list of field to get field of a certain type only

Tags: python, django

This is in the context of an intercepted form instance. I need to get the list of fields, which i'm able to. But i'm not able to get ONLY the image fields.
Here is the code I use:

```
list_of_image_fields = [x.name for x in instance._meta.fields if type(x) == 'django.db.models.fields.files.ImageFieldFile']
```

x.name correctly incarnates each name of all fields form the instance in meta.fields.
With the if statement, I was hoping to get only the ImageField type.
'type(x)' when I put it instead of x.name returns this:

```
<class 'django.db.models.fields.files.ImageFieldFile'> #for each field
```

But it doesn't work in the way  I put it in the if statement which ends up with an empty list.
You can see in the attached image what I get in the debugger for instance._meta.fields.03 (which is field number 03)[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you do `type(x)`, it would give you a type object not a string. Use function `get_internal_type`:

```
list_of_image_fields = [x.name for x in instance._meta.fields if x.get_internal_type() == 'ImageFieldFile']
```

Django [doc about get_internal_type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.get_internal_type).

Comment: Hmmm, they are considered FieldFile, note ImageFieldFile.... I can do ok with that, but anyway to get distinction ?

Comment: That's not possible with `get_internal_type`, because `ImageFieldFile` inherits from `FieldFile` but didn't override the function `get_internal_type`. Check the source code it would make it clearer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/db/models/fields/files/. "Maybe" do `x.__class__.__name__` might show you the right name?

Answer (score 4):

The type isn't a string, its the actual type. So compare it to that!

```
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageFieldFile

list_of_image_fields = [x.name for x in instance._meta.fields if type(x) == ImageFieldFile]
```

What you see in your debugger is actually the result of `str(type(ImageFieldFile))` which is what you get when you convert your type to a string, so a human can read it.